# How to pass environmental variables to a process in a script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

I know you can set environmental variables for a process like so:

```
PATH=/new/path ./binary
```

What I want to do is to create a script with environmental variables and pass the script like so:

```
script ./binary
```

My question is: how to do it and how to do it without setting these environmental variables for a terminal in which I run the process.

### Elaboration:

Inside of my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PWD/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

if [ -z "$APP_DIR" ]; then
    APP_DIR="$PWD/app_dir"
    export APP_DIR
fi
if [ -z "$APP_HOME" ]; then
    APP_HOME="$PWD/app_home"
    export APP_HOME
fi
```

I can source the script for a terminal shell with: `source script.sh`, but I want these variables to be available only to a process I intend to run in my terminal.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit. What do you mean *"What I want to do is to create a script with environmental variables and pass the script like so"*, it is not clear. Maybe add example of script and how the script is used and what is its expected operation

Comment: You  can use `bash -c "PATH=new/path; $@"`

Comment: @NikosM. I've added elaboration

Comment: So you want `( source script.sh; ./a_process_in_your_terminal; )`? or `bash -c "source script.sh; $@" _`?